# Find and replace tagged words from string using python?

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, find

I need to find and replace some tagged words from a paragraph.

```
str = "my name is [tag1]alan[/tag1] . i am a [tag2]python[/tag2] developer."
```

tag1 and tag2 are words I need to find and replace their middle content with another word.
tags are not limited. it may have more than 10. but every tag is enclosed in the same way, like in square brackets, [tag][/tag].

I want a result like this,

```
str = "my name is alan . i am a python developer."
```

Is there any way to do it using regex? without using beautifulsoup.

Comment: So do you want to replace the TAGS or the text BETWEEN tags? Because your example output suggests the former.

Comment: How should a nested tag be treated?

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

string = "my name is [tag1]alan[/tag1]. i am a [tag2]python[/tag2] developer."
print(re.sub(r"(\[.*?\])", "", string))
# --> my name is alan. i am a python developer.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following regular expression:

```
import re

my_str = 'my name is [tag1]alan[/tag1]. i am a [tag2]python[/tag2] developer.'

re.sub(r'\[[/]*tag\d+?\]', '', my_str )
```

output:

```
'my name is alan . i am a python developer.'
```

regex explanation:

- `\[` =  start with `[`
- `[/]*` = next charcter can be `/` or not
- `tag` = must contain the string `tag`
- `\d+?`= must contain a number
- `\]` = ends with `]`